# Оптимальный алгоритм нахождения ближайшей точки к заданной

Tags: алгоритм, gps, координаты

Есть множество точек (с координатами по широте и долготе, не суть), на вход подается точка с фиксированными координатами. Требуется найти самую близкую к заданной точке. Есть ли оптимальный алгоритм, не представляющий собой  полный перебор по расстояниям от заданной к просматриваемой ?

Comment: Если можно предварительную обработку, то кластеризация?

Comment: Вот вам список методов: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Comment: @VladD, да, конечно я видел список методов, не подскажите какой из них наиболее прост в реализации?